# What is on the first line of an XML document?

Tags: xml, xsd

So before we write the XML Schema, a lot of tutorials use this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
```

or

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

My question is, what is this part for? What is that website specifically and why do we use it? Are there other methods to do this?

If it helps, I am doing this to convert an excel worksheet into XML.

Comment: Learn about XML namespaces

Answer (score 2):

### XML Declaration

`<?xml version='1.0'?>` is an [**XML declaration**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl) and is not particular to XSDs but to XML documents in general.

> [Definition: XML documents should begin with an **XML declaration**
> which specifies the version of XML being used.]

As an XSD is an XML document, it may also have an XML declaration.

Here is the BNF of an XML declaration (`XMLDecl`) with links to the definitions of its constituent parts:

> `XMLDecl ::= '<?xml'` [`VersionInfo`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S) [`EncodingDecl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S)`?` [`SDDecl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S)`?` [`S`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S)`? '?>'`

**Note:** [Only one XML declaration is permitted in well-formed XML, and it must be at the top if anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251895/290085).  If you violate this requirement, you'll see an error such as

> `The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.`

and you'll have to [fix the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/290085) before your XML will be [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

---

### XML Schema Instance Namespace

`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is a [namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) declaration for the special **[XML Schema instance namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions)**.  As a namespace URI, its purpose is to facilitate control of grouping of component name.  [An XML namespace URI does not have to be retrievable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613891/290085).

**See also**

- [What are XML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128389/what-are-xml-namespaces-for) for regarding the purpose of namespaces
  in general.
- [Schema-Related Markup in Documents Being Validated](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions) for XSD attributes
  that use `xsi` in particular.  (`xsi:type`, `xsi:nil`, `xsi:schemaLocation`, and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`)

Answer (score 1):

XML declaration. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-prolog-dtd for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
```

1.0 is the current version of XML. And the number might change for future versions. This is a mandatory field and it indicates which version of XML standard this file conforms to.

```
encoding="UTF-8"
```

This mean the file is encoded in UTF-8. This is optional since this is the default character encoding in XML.

```
standalone="yes"
```

standalone indicates whether if the current XML document depends on an external markup declaration. This is also optional.

```
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

This is the XML Schema Instance namespace. After having this declared you can use attributes such as schemaLocation.

See similar answer: [Is xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" a special case in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615892/is-xmlnsxsi-http-www-w3-org-2001-xmlschema-instance-a-special-case-in-xml)