# Can I add an additional attribute to the xml declaration (first line) of an xml file?

Tags: xml, xml-declaration

Is it legal xml syntax to add an additional attribute (to indicate a file-type, for instance) to the xml declaration at the top of an xml file?

(See, e.g., [What is on the first line of an XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835870/what-is-on-the-first-line-of-an-xml-document))

Answer (score 1):

It took me a bit of digging to verify that the answer is **NO**: According to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl), the xml declaration can **only include** the *`xml version`, `encoding`,* and *`standalone document declaration`.*