# XML error during deserialize

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have problem when I'm trying to deserialize an XML to object. My XML look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Products
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AllProducts>
        <Product>
            <ID>8</ID>
            <GID>51280</GID>
            <Kod>RNIKAKC1.6</Kod>
            <Name>SB-800</Name>
            <Ean>0018208048014</Ean>
            <CommodityGroup>
                <ID>86</ID>
                <Name>AKCESORIA FOTO</Name>
                <Path>
                    <Category>
                        <ID>60798</ID>
                        <Name>ARCHIWALNE</Name>
                    </Category>
                </Path>
            </CommodityGroup>
         </Product>
....
Next products
...
```

My method code:

```
var MemoryStream = APIAccess.DownloadFileToStream("example.xml", "exampleContainer");
            using (MemoryStream)
            {
                MemoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(MemoryStream))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommodityGroup));
                    var products = serializer.Deserialize(StreamReader);
                }
            }
```

Method DownloadFileToStream is working good, because it is useful in other classes.

I'm geting error:

> InvalidOperationException: Products xmlns='' was not expected.

I want to create object of a Node CommodityGroup. I've created class selecting this node, coping it and pasting in the new class like Paste Special -> XML

Attributes of this class looks like:

```
[Serializable()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "CommodityGroup", IsNullable = false)]
```

I don't know to fix it. When I'm adding into XML Serializer param new XmlRootAttribute("Products"), I'm getting "0" values.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Drop the namespaces and it should work. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615892/is-xmlnsxsi-http-www-w3-org-2001-xmlschema-instance-a-special-case-in-xml For more info.

Comment: I can't change xml file

Comment: Did you manually add `Namespace = "CommodityGroup"` to the generated class? Why? Submitted xml does not contain this namespace.

Comment: Yeah, automatically was generated ` Namespace = ""`. Just trying every  possible way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deserialize only part of an xml document, you should skip unnecessary nodes.

Do it using `XmlReader`.

```
using (StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(MemoryStream))
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(StreamReader))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("CommodityGroup");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommodityGroup));
    var commodityGroup = (CommodityGroup)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

Comment: With that method I have same exception but instead Products xmls, I have CommodityGroup xmls.

I've added to serializer parameter `new XmlRootAttribute("CommodityGroup")`

Now I have exception `OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.`

Comment: I've changed type of my values in CommodityGroup class from ushort to Int and it seems work. I need to debug it more, and I will gave respond ;)